# Preserving richtextbox formatting when editing 1 line

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox

I have a program which logs to a richtextbox, the logs are color coded depending on the error/event.

Here's how I add text to my logs with default style.

```
rtbLogs.AppendText("Log Text")
```

Here's how I add text when they're colored.

```
rtbLogs.Select(rtbLogs.TextLength, 0)
rtbLogs.SelectionFont = New Font(rtbLogs.Font, FontStyle.Regular)
rtbLogs.SelectionColor = Color.Red 'Settings the font styles
rtbLogs.AppendText("Error Text")
rtbLogs.SelectionFont = rtbLogs.Font
rtbLogs.SelectionColor = rtbLogs.ForeColor 'reset style to default
```

Now sometimes I need to update 1 line in my log, after editing all formatting disappears. After editing the next logs I add with be formatted how I want but disappears again if I edit 1 line.

Here's how I edit a line.

```
Dim lines() As String = Me.rtbLogs.Lines
lines(5) = "Updated Text"
Me.rtbLogs.Lines = lines
```

How do I preserve the formatting?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/594850/DeleteplusaplusspecifiedpluslineplusinplusRichText

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe something like this

```
Me.rtbLogs.Rtf = Me.rtbLogs.Rtf.Replace(Me.rtbLogs.Lines(5), "Updated Text")
```